# Cytoscape equivalent of graphviz URL/href node attribute when exporting SVG?

Tags: svg, href, graphviz, graph-layout, cytoscape

In the past I've using graphviz's node "label", "URL" (or "href") and "tooltip" attributes to generate SVG graphics where the nodes have the text label, mouse-over displays the tooltip, and clicking the node (assuming your browser is displaying the svg) takes you to the URL target (and all those strings can be different).

Right now I'm trying to generate the same sort of thing in Cytoscape.  Exporting svg works nicely, but linkage of nodes to external URLs seems all tied up with Cytoscape's "linkout" feature; while this seems very powerful while you're actually *using* Cytoscape, it's not clear to me whether there's some way of getting it to produce clickable nodes or labels (I'd settle for either) in an exported SVG.  The URLs I want to link to are a node attribute of my imported graph.

Is there something I'm missing in Cytoscape which will create links in exported SVG ?  Any suggestions for alternative approaches ?  e.g some way of getting labels to be arbitrary HTML including `<a href=...>...</a>` ?

My "plan B" is to postprocess the exported SVG, but it'd be nicer to have Cytoscape do it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as my further use of the tool permitted me to determine, Cytoscape just doesn't have this capability.